# How to import `.jar` file to lua code and create java instance?

Tags: java, jar, lua, luaj

Here is ex [how to call new instance of java obj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35392230/2425851), but how to import `mylib.jar` is not explained

For ex. I have `mylib.jar` and there is class `com.example.MyClass`.

```
    public class MyClass{
    public String getHelloPersonName(String name){
          return "Hello, " + name;
    }
```

I want to create the java class instance and call this method

**How to import the `.jar` file to the `lua` code, and create an instance of `MyClass` and call method from it?**

```
function init()

end
```

Comment: I'm not sure about importing the file into Lua, but maybe you can do something with [os.execute](http://lua-users.org/wiki/OsLibraryTutorial), and call `java -jar mylib.jar` with arguments?

Comment: @Mark Here is ex how to call new instance of java obj https://stackoverflow.com/a/35392230/2425851, but how to import `mylib.jar` is not explained

Comment: Create `program.lua` assuming your lib is already loaded in Java.  Then run `java -cp "lib/luaj-jse-3.0.1.jar;/path/to/mylib.jar" lua program.lua`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff nothing happens after run of the command

Comment: @NickUnuchek - Please show your `program.lua`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff `function init() end`. Egor please explain fully , because I'm new in lua. I'm android dev.

Comment: The link you posted shows an example how to create instance of Java class by using `luajava.newInstance()`.  Try it inside your `program.lua`.  Read LuaJ API about other operations (passing and returning values and so on).